# Converting Year into 12/31/xxxx Format in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

I have a list of years stored in a `Pandas.DataFrame` (`column=df[0]`) that looks like this:

```
0      1939
1      1977
2      1965
3      1982
4      1997
5      1956
```

What's the easiest method to convert these dates into `12/31/xxxx` format where "xxxx" is equal to the year? I need it converted into that format for Excel to recognize the numbers as dates.

**Note:** I found a quick hack for this in Excel using find and replace, but would like to know how to do this in Python, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to transform the data to the format using something like this. Date would start off as the year and be set to 12/31/year

```
date = '12/31/{0}'.format(date)
```

In pandas context

```
df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: '12/31/{0}'.format(x))
```

Comment: That works perfectly. That was along the lines of what I was thinking, but wasn't totally sure how to do it.

Comment: Happy to help, I find myself visiting the docs for pandas quite a bit. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
In [1094]: pd.to_datetime(df.year, format='%Y') + pd.offsets.YearEnd(1)
Out[1094]:
0   1939-12-31
1   1977-12-31
2   1965-12-31
3   1982-12-31
4   1997-12-31
5   1956-12-31
Name: year, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.astype()` to get as a string and the construct your dates like:

#### Code:

```
'12/31/' + df[0].astype(str)
```

#### Test Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1939, 1977, 1965, 1982, 1997, 1956])
print(df)
print('12/31/' + df[0].astype(str))
```

#### Result:

```
      0
0  1939
1  1977
2  1965
3  1982
4  1997
5  1956

0    12/31/1939
1    12/31/1977
2    12/31/1965
3    12/31/1982
4    12/31/1997
5    12/31/1956
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. I probably should've thought of that, but still a bit of a newb with this.